# Много папок в node_modules , причина в Gulp или npm

Tags: gulp, npm

При установки какого либо пакета, например **gulp-sass** , в папке **node_modules** возникает много папок. Раньше такого у меня не было, не могу понять в чем причина. Неужели это новый **npm** так работает?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В июне прошлого года вышла [3-я версия](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0) `npm`.

Одним из её ключевых нововведений является плоская структура каталогов - зависимости практически всех пакетов теперь устанавливаются в корень папки `node_modules`. Внутрь же папок самих пакетов, они попадают только при наличии конфликтов.

Данное нововведение прежде всего резко сокращает дублирование, снижая затраты ресурсов на хранение и исполнение кода нескольких одинаковых пакетов внутри проекта.