# При запуске команды npm install подтягивает тучу ненужных модулей, которые не объявлены в package.json

Tags: gulp, npm

Создал файл package.json для работы с gulp

```
{
  "name": "Travel",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.4.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.1.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.1",
    "gulp-uglifycss": "^1.0.5",
    "gulp-uncss": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

При вызове в консоле npm install подтягивает много разных модулей, которых нет в зависимостях. Почему так просиходит? Как корректно подтягивать только те модули, которые описаны в зависимостях файла package.json?

Comment: - Я не думаю, что это дубликат вопроса. У меня на 7 модулей npm подтянул 445 папок. В которых 7 папок - это те модули, которые у меня описаны выше, а все оставшееся, похожи на модули node "из коробки". Т.е. я полагаю, он подтянул модули для node. Это нормально?

Comment: Это нормально, если у вас npm 3. Ответ с бОльшим количеством голосов (а не принятый) по [ссылке выше объясняет](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479306/%d0%9c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-node-modules-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2-gulp-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-npm), почему так происходит.

Comment: - Прошу прощения, но я не понимаю о каких зависимостях идет речь в ответе по ссылке. "зависимости практически всех пакетов теперь устанавливаются в корень папки node_modules." зависимости === dependencies? Если да, то где их можно посмотреть в папке node_modules? Или имеется ввиду, что там лежат сами пакеты? "Внутрь же папок самих пакетов, они попадают только при наличии конфликтов". Это вроде должно сократить дублирование, но может вы объясните, зачем мне в проекте, где есть 7 бананов, нужна горила и джунгли пакетов в придачу, размером более 45МБ. Я не понимаю, мне кажется это не нормально.

Comment: - Т.е. мой проект использует только gulp и никогда не будет использовать пакеты node. Почему он качает >400 папок когда я их никогда использовать не буду? Или вы хотите сказать что это подкачивают свои зависимости  7 обявленных модулей в файле package.json? Тоже как то не похоже на правду. Вы уж извините..

Comment: Нюанс в том, что каждый модуль, который вы устанавливаете, зависит от ряда других модулей, а те в свою очередь тоже имеют зависимости. У каждого модуля тоже есть свой файл package.json, в котором прописаны эти зависимости. Раньше зависимости каждого модуля складывались в его собственную папку node_modules внутри папки самого модуля. Из-за большого уровня вложенности и дублирования пакетов было принято решение в новой версии складывать все зависимости всех модулей на одном уровне.

Comment: - Спасибо. Проанализировал каждый модуль. Оказалось действительно 400 модулей. Это еще и не предел.